# Electron Js - Customise menu bar

Tags: javascript, typescript, electron

I am building a desktop application using Electron (so far supporting only Mac).
I would like to be able to use the [Electron Menu](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/menu) but I cannot figure out if it's possible to use some HTML and JS to fully customised.

So far I am using a `nav` bar in the react application within the renderer but I was wondering if there is a way to achieve the same using the Electron Menu.

For reference I would like to have something similar to the Slack menu bar.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's currently not possible to get a fully customized menu bar using the [Menu API](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/menu). If you want something as custom as the example you gave, you have to code it yourself in your renderer with HTML/CSS/JS.

Here is [the documentation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/window-customization) about what's possible to cusomize on the window. To hide the native titlebar and menus, you can use `titleBarStyle: "hidden"` in your `BrowserWindow` configuration. You will have to use [IPC](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc) to communicate with the main process in order to recreate the native functionalities such as closing the window, minimize the app, etc...

Comment: Thanx, just wanted a confirmation that coding it myself was the way to go.

Comment: @mikey Yep, it is.